# How to make sorting by json fields with mysql db?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Testing Laravel 10 app with spatie/laravel-translatable 6.3 in MySQL 8 and Postgres 14 I found
problem with sorting by json fields. On side of postgres I salved by using orderBy with string :

```
 "name->>'en'"
```

But which decision for mysql ? By default $orderBy = "name" there is no run time error, but ordering does not work...

Comment: Test `$orderBy = "name->>'$.en'"`

Comment: Thanks! looks like it works. Please give a reference where  this functionality explained

Comment: [The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort by JSON fields in MySQL, you can use the JSON_EXTRACT() function. This function will extract a value from a JSON object based on a JSON path. To extract the en value from the name field, you can use the following JSON path:

```
$.name->>'en'
```

You can then use the extracted value in the ORDER BY clause of your SQL query. For example, the following query will order the results by the English value of the name field:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT(name, '$.name->>'en') ASC;
```

Here is an example of how to use the JSON_EXTRACT() function in Laravel:

```
$results = DB::table('table')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(name, "$.name->>'en'")'), 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

This code will return a collection of results ordered by the English value of the name field.

Note that the JSON_EXTRACT() function is not available in MySQL versions older than 8.0. If you are using an older version of MySQL, you will need to use a different method to sort by JSON fields. One option is to use the JSON_UNQUOTE() function to convert the JSON object to a string, and then use the STRCMP() function to compare the strings.

Here is an example of how to use the JSON_UNQUOTE() and STRCMP() functions to sort by JSON fields in MySQL versions older than 8.0:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY STRCMP(JSON_UNQUOTE(name->>'en'),SON_UNQUOTE(name->>'en')) ASC;
```

This code will return a collection of results ordered by the English value of the name field.

Comment: *you can use the following JSON path: `$.name->>'en'`* - incorrect.